# How to switch between XmlTextWriter and XmlWriter?

Tags: c#

Microsoft recommend to use `XmlWriter` instead of `XmlTextWriter`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo)).WriteObject(writer, info);
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

How to correctly use `XmlWriter` in my method instead of `XmlTextWriter`?

Comment: For clarification, per the link provided, Microsoft recommends "that you create XmlWriter instances by using the XmlWriter.Create method and the XmlWriterSettings class."  That being the case, the answer provided by @OndrejSvejdar would be inline with that recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the factory method `Create` on `XmlWriter` class like:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
{
  new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo)).WriteObject(writer, info)
}
```

Comment: Why you didn't use `StringWriter`?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it without `XmlWriter`

```
public static string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
{
    string result = String.Empty;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo));
        dcs.WriteObject(ms, info);
        sw.Flush();

        ms.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();               
    }             

    return result;
}
```